# Difference between tf.random_normal_initializer and tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have:

```
init1 = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)
init2 = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.02)
```

Both these seem to be giving similar results, when used to create tf.Variables:

```
tf.Variable(init1(shape=[3], dtype=tf.float32))
>> <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([-0.02076386,  0.02649704, -0.01076219], dtype=float32)>

tf.Variable(init2(shape=[3], dtype=tf.float32)) 
 >> <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 0.01218272, -0.00031702, -0.00397457], dtype=float32)>
```

And when used with a tensorflow layer:

`tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization(gamma_initializer=init1)` and `tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization(gamma_initializer=init2)` in my case.

What is the difference between `tf.random_normal_initializer` and `tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal` and when is one used instead of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between them. Both are equal to use and choice.

You are getting different output, because they are random generator. If you want to make sure they are both the same, try to set `seed` argument:

```
init1 = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02, seed=42)
init2 = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.02, seed=42)

print(tf.Variable(init1(shape=[3], dtype=tf.float32)))
print(tf.Variable(init2(shape=[3], dtype=tf.float32)))
```

Result:

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 0.00031634, -0.03180174,  0.00207189], dtype=float32)>
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 0.00031634, -0.03180174,  0.00207189], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering, that if there is no difference, what is the point of having 2 separate functions doing the same thing? Is it just an implementational detail that has to do with the way Tensorflow has been built up on pre existing versions?

Comment: @skinnybb I don't really know what is behind the scenes. I just know that both of them have the same use case, the same input arguments and the same output results. Sometimes it happens due to different needs in different versions, and gradually they will be integrated in the future versions, in order to keep backward compatibility. In this case it maybe due to merging TF with Keras. Formerly, Keras and TF were 2 separate libraries. TF had its own initializer and Keras had its own. But after merging these 2, you may find some libraries both in Keras and TF.

Comment: It seems that even if you don't set a seed then init2 produces allways the same outcome but init1 not.